# JDialog appears in the top left corner of screen, when when I've set it's position to the center of its parent

Tags: java, swing, dialog

Before I initialized my dialog as

```
  addQuestionDialog = new JDialog(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this),"Add    question);
```

and I set the location of the dialog to be at the center of its parent by calling:

```
addQuestionDialog.setLocationRelativeTo(this)
```

This works and displays the dialog at the center of its parent, however when I set the dialog to be a modal dialog, it completely ignores the set method and displays the dialog in the top left corner of my screen.

```
addQuestionDialog = new JDialog(SwingUtilities.windowForComponent(this),"Add question", Dialog.ModalityType.DOCUMENT_MODAL);
```

Comment: Go to [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213266/how-do-i-center-a-jdialog-on-screen](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/213266/how-do-i-center-a-jdialog-on-screen)

Comment: I know how to re-position a dialog, the issue is that a modal dialog ignores my re-positioning, whereas a modeless dialog works perfectly fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> however when I set the dialog to be a modal dialog, it completely ignores the set method and displays the dialog in the top left corner of my screen.

The order of the code should be:

```
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(..);
dialog.setVisible(true );
```

I'm guessing you are using:

```
dialog.setVisible(true );
dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(..); // this is not executed until the dialog is closed.
```

Answer (score 0):

This JDialog code sequence works for me:

```scala
   setModal(true)
   pack()
   setLocationRelativeTo(frame)
   setVisible(true)
```

Placing the setLocationRelativeTo(frame) line before the pack() line results in the off-center placement of the dialog. Interesting.:)